# Apps in Plesk catalog

Tags: plesk

Are the apps available in the Plesk catalog are free when they do not have the buy option? e.g. "readyscript shop" has only install to click. This means it is free to use or I still should purchase a license from the app website?
Thanks,
Selim

Answer (score 1):

If an application in the Plesk catalog doesn't has the "Buy" button, it just means that it's not possible to buy the extension via the official Plesk store.

Depending on the application, it is still possible, that you have to own a license to use it.